# Is there a idiom or term to describe someone who don't see you as the same level as them?

Tags: word-choice, vocabulary, idioms

The best I can think of are the combination of:
讽刺意味 (to have the "smell" of irony on you) and
很偏激 (very extreme or biased)。

举个例子/For example：
Everything you say or do is viewed as ignorant（天真） or immature by that person; kind of like they see you with a bias and with a superiority complex.

又举个例子/Example 2:
The reason they see you are ignorant is because *they are* ignorant and not understanding of others, as shown through analyzing their actions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[狗眼看人低](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E7%8B%97%E7%9C%BC%E7%9C%8B%E4%BA%BA%E4%BD%8E)**

> (figuratively) to act like a snob; to look down on someone even when one is no better

**[目中无人](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E7%9B%AE%E4%B8%AD%E7%84%A1%E4%BA%BA#Chinese)**

> to be prideful; to be haughty; to be arrogant

Comment: Interesting, interesting. I never knew the term "狗眼". I am assuming it is like comparing the face of a dog that looks disgusted with the face of someone looking down on someone?

Comment: @Monokuma A dog's eyes are at a lower level compared to a human's. Everything it sees is from a low level (從低處看), including looking at humans.  However, the term 低看 happens to mean look down upon.  Thus 狗眼看人低 (dogs look people from a low level) is interpreted as 'look down upon people with dog's eyes (Ignorant view point) ' instead of looking up at people -- It is a word play